# How to Highlight a custom cell in a table view at regular time interval ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I have a table view where in I have loaded my custom cell. I want to highlight each cell in a regular time interval without any user interaction once the table view is loaded. please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this line of code and try this.
//add this in viewdidload method

```
    NSTimer *timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(highlighted) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

   -(void)highlighted
   {
        [customcellobject setHighlighted:YES animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, The cells are getting highlighted but not in a sequence. Its random. any further steps of guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: so for that help you not up the arrow for increase reputation Please tell me reason?Then I will try your further help.

Comment: But I tell you the answer thats my work You should use your timer in for loop and in for loop pass the condition in that condition loop move again again one by one.

Comment: for (int i = 0 ; i < [array count]; i++) like this only

Comment: yaay got it. this is what I used
if(count2<count){
        count2 = count2+1;
    NSIndexPath *path= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:a inSection:0];
    [self.tableview selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
    a=a+1;
    }
Thanks

Comment: So at least now up my reputation arrow and my ans is correct then mark it correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSTimer to fire action of selection at specific time intervals that you want.

EDIT -

```
NSTimer *timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(highlightMyCell) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]
```

Now in highlightMyCell method -

```
-(void)highlightMyCell {
    // Provide implementation to highlight the cell.
}
```

Comment: can you please explain a bit specific.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, The cells are getting highlighted but not in a sequence. Its random. any further steps of guidance will be appreciated

Comment: what do you mean by random and exactly what you want now?

Answer (score 1):

Use an NSTimer than invokes a method that flips between sending the selectors `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` and `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:` at each fire of the timer.

Comment: after selecRowAtIndexPath you will need to call didselectRowAtIndexPath method then only the corresponding cell will be highlighted.